# Allow inserting new data lines but not changing formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

is there any way how can I allow inserting new data lines for the user (with whom I share sheet) but not changing formulas?

My case: I created formulas for example for dropdown list in lines, other formulas for cells, etc. Now I want to allow the user to insert data to these lines, but I want to prevent him to change these formulas (ideally he should not be able to see or copy these formulas or entire sheet).

I know I can protect sheets/cells but this entirely disables edit for the user. 
Is there any way please to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have two sheets - one for him/her and one for you. in your sheet you will have all your formulas. then you just connect these two sheets with `IMPORTRANGE` formulas (for example columns A, B, C from his/her sheet into your A, B, C ...and then your D column with formulas imported into his/her sheet' D column)

another way would be to use `ARRAYFORMULA` variants for all your formulas which would be sitting in a safe zone on the first row.

Comment: this could work. Thank you! I will try it and then I mark this as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can protect only selected parts of the sheet.

1. Go to Data -> Protected sheets and ranges...
2. Click on Add a sheet or range in the sidebar.
3. Enter name of the range.
4. Select Sheet as the option.
5. Check Except certain cells.
6. Add all the ranges you want the user to be allowed to edit.

Hope this helps!